# coldfusion xml parse address types

Tags: xml, coldfusion

Given the following XML:

```
<Contact>
   <ContactID>41111-f15a-4fa1-b643-47877608f557</ContactID>
   <ContactStatus>ACTIVE</ContactStatus>
   <Name>ABC Ltd</Name>
   <EmailAddress>xxx@xxx.co</EmailAddress>
   <SkypeUserName>xxxdemo</SkypeUserName>
   <Addresses>
      <Address>
         <AddressType>STREET</AddressType>
         <AddressLine1>Radio XXX</AddressLine1>
         <AddressLine2>4388 Ballarat Highway</AddressLine2>
         <City>Melbourne</City>
         <PostalCode>3133</PostalCode>
      </Address>
      <Address>
         <AddressType>POBOX</AddressType>
         <AddressLine1>Radio xx House</AddressLine1>
         <AddressLine2>P O Box 1111</AddressLine2>
         <City>Melbourne</City>
         <Region>VIC</Region>
         <PostalCode>3133</PostalCode>
      </Address>
   </Addresses>
   <Phones>
      <Phone>
         <PhoneType>MOBILE</PhoneType>
      </Phone>
      <Phone>
         <PhoneType>DEFAULT</PhoneType>
         <PhoneNumber>1112222</PhoneNumber>
         <PhoneAreaCode>03</PhoneAreaCode>
      </Phone>
      <Phone>
         <PhoneType>FAX</PhoneType>
      </Phone>
      <Phone>
         <PhoneType>DDI</PhoneType>
      </Phone>
   </Phones>
   <UpdatedDateUTC>2012-07-26T20:06:00.75</UpdatedDateUTC>
   <IsSupplier>false</IsSupplier>
   <IsCustomer>true</IsCustomer>
</Contact>
<Contact>
   Another contact...
</Contact>
```

I can access the contactIDs via:

```
<cfset aContacts = XmlSearch(sResponse,"//Contact") />
<cfloop index="i" from="1" to="#arrayLen(aContacts)#">
  <cfset sContactID = aContacts[i].ContactID>
</cfloop>
```

But how do I parse the various address types, e.g. as follows:

```
<cfloop index="i" from="1" to="#arrayLen(aContacts)#">
  <cfset sContactID = aContacts[i].ContactID>
  <cfset sStreetAddressLine1 = ??>
  <cfset sStreetAddressLine2 = ??>
  <cfset sStreetAddressCity = ??>
  <cfset sStreetAddressPostalCode = ??>
  <cfset sPOBoxAddressLine1 = ??>
  <cfset sPOBoxAddressLine2 = ??>
  <cfset sPOBoxAddressCity = ??>
  <cfset sPOBoxAddressPostalCode = ??>
</cfloop>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should do it:-

```
<cfset aContacts = XmlSearch(sResponse,"//Contact")>

<cfloop index="i" from="1" to="#arrayLen(aContacts)#">
    <cfset sContactID = aContacts[i].ContactID>
    <cfset aAddresses = aContacts[i].addresses.xmlChildren>
    <cfset sStreetAddressLine1 = aAddresses[1].AddressLine1>
    <cfset sStreetAddressLine2 = aAddresses[1].AddressLine2>
    <cfset sStreetAddressCity = aAddresses[1].City>
    <cfset sStreetAddressPostalCode = aAddresses[1].PostalCode>
    <cfset sPOBoxAddressLine1 = aAddresses[2].AddressLine1>
    <cfset sPOBoxAddressLine2 = aAddresses[2].AddressLine2>
    <cfset sPOBoxAddressCity = aAddresses[2].City>
    <cfset sPOBoxAddressPostalCode = aAddresses[2].PostalCode>
</cfloop>
```

Please bear in mind that assuming that the second address is the PO Box address might not be exactly what the person who created this XML intended so you may be making some incorrect assumptions there. Also you should really check the length of the array `aAddresses` to avoid any run time errors. Hopefully this will get you going though.